# why does useEffect not re-run having setState as dependency?

Tags: react-hooks, use-effect

I don't know why useEffect doesn't re-run when I call useState dependecy, I tried to pass state as useEffect dependency but it makes an infinite loop. I would like to run useEffect just when setState is called.

is there any way to do so?

```
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect initial state ')
    fetch(API)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => {
          setState(response.data);
        })
    
      }, [setState]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop is caused because you are changing the state inside the effect which then retriggers it so that's expected.

This is a design issue where you need to setup your effect to be more granular and change only the state that it needs to and react to only the state that should trigger a refresh.

Comment: Thanks!, I haven't noticed that

Comment: Great. Please vote/accept if you found this helpful. Also to be clear you were closer to correct with using state NOT setstate. Even though it was in a loop, hopefully now you see why it got into an infinite loop since it was doing exactly what it was supposed to! And that means you can totally design a way out of it that's appropriate to your domain! If you still need help let me know.